# Xamarin with Microsoft SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to code an Android and iOS application for my thesis for school. It is the first time I am actually working with database and I don't have a clue what I am doing.

My teacher won't (because he doesn't have a clue either) help, so I am coming here. I am running Android Studio on my PC, along with the Microsoft SQL Server database. From what I read online, I would need to develop a REST API or something like that but as I said I don't have a clue what I am doing and I just want to have my application running on my PC for testing.

I tried this and a couple of other things but the main problem I am phasing is that I am getting a connection error. The IP of my PC is 192.168.1.41 I am running Android studio with a pixel phone running android 13. The name of the database is `personeelgegevens`. The name in SQL Server of my pc is `HP_PROBOOK_G8\MSSQLSERVER02`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ShowMeYourTools
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginUI : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Inlog knop
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txbEmail.Text == "ADMIN" && txbWachtwoord.Text == "ADMIN")
            {
                Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ShowMeYourTools.HomePage());
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Foutive ingave", "De ingave komt niet overeen met bij ons gekende accounts.", "OK");
            }
        }

        //Wordt niet gebruikt
        private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = @"Server=192.168.1.41;Database=personeelgegevens;Trusted_Connection=true";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    DisplayAlert("OK", "OK I am Connected", "OK");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
                }
            }
        }

        //Wachtwoord vergeten lijntje text
        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ShowMeYourTools.PasswordReset());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that anyone can help

The line of code when it crashes is when it is trying to connect.
con.Open();

As asked the Error thrown
[Image of Error this is only a part of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON91U.png)

Update I fixt it by not using "proximus" my internet provider but "telenet"

Comment: First, you should never connect directly from a mobile app to a db server.  You should, as you already mentioned, use a REST API.  This is extensively documented.  Microsoft has samples that show how to do the client and server sides of this process.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: Second, the only concrete problem you've mentioned is "connection error".  You haven't told us what specific line causes the error, what the specific exception is, or what the stack trace is.  That is all basic debugging info you should provide without being asked.

Comment: I updated the question to include the error and when it is thrown. Look I know I should use a REST API. But I am only 17 years old don't have any real coding experience and it just has to run to show that it works.

Comment: that's better, but please do not post errors or code as images.  That said, the error message gives you several useful tips: verify that the instance name is correct and that the server is configured to allow remote connections

Comment: I know it is not the best as an image but due to it running in an android emulator i wasn't able to copy the code. That said I know remote connections are on because I can connect in a normal wpf program. I also suspect it is something to do with the server name or like going from an emulated environment to like my pc or something I was hoping someone knew what the requirements where for a connection string. I tried it with the string I used in the wpf program but no luck.  string connectionString = "Server=HP_PROBOOK_G8\\MSSQLSERVER02;Database=personeelgegevens;Trusted_Connection=Yes";

Comment: is the WPF app running on the same PC as the SQL instance?  If so, then that is NOT a remote connection.  However, an Android emulator will always appear as a remote connection even if it is running on the same machine.

Comment: So thank you for your comment so yes indeed it was running local. So I configured it so it would work with an IP address but no luck I finally got the port 1433 working but I still can't connect with my IP

Comment: is it the **exact** same error as you were getting before?

Comment: I didn’t try to run my code yet because I now was just trying to connect with my database with my IP instead of server name. I got it working to the point that if I connect with my server name I can set the port behind the name and that works. Before I couldn’t do that. So atleast my remote connection kind of works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly not a complete answer, but just try to get you started.

## Three tier system

What you found from the internet is correct, that for this system you will need 3 tiers,

- An Android app running on the phone or emulator
- A SQL Server instance that stores the data
- A REST API web app hosting somewhere in between.

## REST API with ASP.NET Core 7

Microsoft does have a guide on how to write REST API with .NET 7, so that you can follow it,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

## Let ASP.NET Core Connect with SQL Server

Then you should prepare the SQL Server instance following Microsoft documentation or books, and let your web app connects to it via ADO.NET,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/microsoft-ado-net-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

> Note that you can also use Entity Framework if you like, but ADO.NET is more than enough for simple projects.

## Let Android App Consume REST API

This is the simplest part, as you can use `HttpClient` and tons of examples are out there.

However, instead of using legacy Xamarin.Android you should use .NET MAUI from .NET 7 now to build your Android app,

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-maui-dotnet-7/

BTW, if you don't know networking of emulator very well, read this,

https://halfblood.pro/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3

Comment: Thank you for your in deapth answer I probably will build my rest api at some point but now it will not be very useful because the remote connect to my sql server is still not working. I configured everything like the internet says but no luck my port works but not with my IP

Comment: The .net Maui looks promising do you think it would be hard to convert my xamarin project to this (I only made a couple of GUIs not real code yet) and what would be the advantages